# Problem with NotifyIcon: "Hide Inactive Icons" not working

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon, systray

I am using C# (.NET 3.5) and use the NotifyIcon to enable "Minimize to Systray". Everything is working great, except that the shell registers the systray icon with the title "No title" when you look at the start menu properties -> "Hide Inactive Icons".

Also changing the setting for that systray icon to "Always Show" or "Always Hide" is not remembered as soon as the icon is removed and put back to the systray.

Any idea how to register the systray icon in a way that this setting can be persisted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be using the text in the "text" property of your NotifyIcon to use as the tooltip in the notification area and also in the list for hiding inactive icons (etc.)

It may not be remembering your settings if you've set the text property to be blank (hard to say for sure without seeing your code)